# Check domain validity with wildcard resolver

Tags: php, dns

I have a site where I record links to user-provided web pages.  I only want to record them if they are valid.

I was using `checkdnsrr($domain, 'A')` to check domain validity, and I noticed this was always returning `true`.  I'm on shared hosting (so I can't change anything).  I reported a bug to the server admin, and he replied:

> We use OpenDNS for our resolvers on the servers. Their resolvers will return an IP/DNS record even for invalid domains as they have a wildcard set up to point any invalid domains to a default IP. Because of this all domains you enter will show as having an A record.

Okay then.

I want to avoid using `cURL` on an invalid domain as this would be a waste, but there is actually a bigger problem.  I believe this resolver returns some kind of error page like "This domain does not exist," and emits a 200 or some other supposedly valid return status.  I use this status to confirm that the page is indeed valid, so now any invalid domain will be recorded as valid by my site.

(Humorously, a valid domain with an invalid URL that leads to a page emitting 404 or some other error status will *not* be recorded).

Anyway, is there some other way to check domain validity?  I don't mind using some third party site.

Comment: Using curl would probably be pointless as well - it'd be using the same resolver as PHP and still end with whatever IP(s) that opendns is serving up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenDNS (and others that do this) usually return the same IP for all domains that should come up NXDOMAIN (invalid). If the result of your check is that IP, consider it invalid. It's one extra check, but it should be a valid workaround.

Comment: This sounds like a good start .. do you know how to a) get the IP of a domain from a string in PHP and b) figure out what this "same IP for all domains" is?  Also, would I have to worry about it changing from time to time unexpectedly?

Comment: @tandu, It looks like you can get the ip with [gethostbyname()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php). You'll probably need to run that from the host once with a known-invalid host (eg: dfgdfgdg.com), to get the ip you need to consider "invalid". You're at the mercy of the dns provider as to when they change things, but I'd expect it should be fairly stable.